# R: read and write encoded texts properly

Tags: r, encoding

I can't seem to get the encoding work properly. And trying to reproduce the problem leads to even more surprising results:

1. The real problem

I am reading in file that has text in language that contains characters such as "ā, č, š, ū" etc.

such as `names <- read.table("file", sep = "|", header = T)`

by calling `View(names)`, all of the special characters appear as they should be:

[image: View(names) output]

However, by calling simply `names` R returns:

[image: names output]

And pretty much the same gibberish appears when I try to write the file. And this is the problem I want to solve. File with broken characters won't cut it.

2. Trying to reproduce:

`a <- c("Šrilanka", "Ķīna", "Kanāda", "Ēģipte")
 write.csv(a, "test.csv", row.names = F)
 b <- read.table("test.csv", header = T)`

This yields quite surprising results as resulting file test.csv is perfectly readable, however when I read it back into R I get the opposite problem.

calling `View(b)` yields:

[image]

While calling simply `b` yields:

[image]

Perfectly fine text.

So.. back to the essence of problem. I have set my default text encoding in R as "UTF-8". I have tried using stringi package with mixed results:

```
> stri_enc_mark(names$city)
[1] "native" "native" "native" "native" "ASCII"  "native"
```

forcing some encoding:

```
> stri_encode(names$city, "ASCII", "UTF-8")
[1] "Balo��i"       "R��ga"         "Kr��slava"     "BAB��TES NOV." "Jelgava"       "R��ga"
```

I have a suspicion that problem occurs when initially reading the file. However the fact that using `View(names)` yields expected results with all special symbols in place kinda throws me off balance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved my own problem by doing this:

```
read.table(text = readLines("file.csv", encoding = "UTF-8"), sep = "|", header = T)
```

Somehow reading in line by line and forcing an encoding this way kinda works. However, it dramatically increases the read-in time. Which is already a whole different problem, not related to this post.

Answer (score -1):

```
names <- read.table("file", sep = "|", header = T, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: So far I have changed encoding through RStudio Global Options menu, have tried at least 10 different so far, with restarting of R after each time. Nope.. Maybe I should choose some specific encoding? RStudio has an impressive list there..

Comment: @A.Val. how about opening the file and assuming it's UTF-8? Changed my answer. If it works, it should more efficient than reading line per liene.